# Magento 2. How to set deploy mode to production (in NGINX and Apache config)?

Tags: magento2, nginx, apache

Anyone knows `How to set deploy mode to production (in NGINX and Apache config).`

Thanks for your collaborations.

Comment: is this worked? OW , idea is worked:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set production  mode from  **apache config files**.by set-up environment variable

Add below code at config

> SetEnv MAGE_MODE "production"

For ngnix at config file

```
location / {
...
   fastcgi_param   MAGE_MODE  production; #MAGE_MODE = production
...
}
```